# Dygraph not shown on collapsed jQuery mobile collapsible widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dygraphs

I have multiple dygraphs plots, which I would like to group in a collapsible jQuery widget, so that one could only show some groups of graphs. Sadly, this only works if the collapsible div is expanded at the start, if I start collapsed, the graph will not be drawn after expanding.

Although not a real solution, I could start with all all elements expanded. However, if the collapses some graphs and switches pages in between, they same problem occurs.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnb7q5ws/) which shows the problem - set `data-collapsed="false"` and the graph will be drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try calling `g.resize()` or `g.updateOptions()` on all the charts when the widget expands. These should be no-ops, but their effect is to force dygraphs to recalculate the size of its container `<div>`, which has changed due to the expanding widget.

To my knowledge, there's no way to tell from JavaScript when a DOM Element becomes visible or is resized in ways other than window resizes. This affects other JS libraries as well.

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle that calls g.resize() on collapsibleexpand: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/dnb7q5ws/2/ it seems to work.

Comment: Thank you, that explains why I sometimes had invisible graphs until I resized the browser window. Your solution works, feels a bit hacky to add another event listener, but it seems this is how hiding in javascript works. It might by worth to mention, that `g.resize()` and `g.updateOptions()` do not behave the same way: The latter one only works if the graph was created while expanded. Too bad, because now I actually have to add a resize, whereas otherwise I could just call my already existent update function.